# CUDA, Boost and Cmake "string sub-command REGEX, mode MATCHALL needs at least 5 arguments total to command."

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake, cuda

I want to use CUDA, Boost for my application and find myself stuck with the following error message

```sh
$ cmake ..

CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/BoostDetectToolset-1.71.0.cmake:5 (string):
  string sub-command REGEX, mode MATCHALL needs at least 5 arguments total to
  command.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_program_options-1.71.0/boost_program_options-config.cmake:24 (include)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:117 (find_package)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:182 (boost_find_component)
  /home/long/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/211.7442.42/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:460 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Boost toolset is unknown (compiler  )
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

My CMake file looks like following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(chaotic_attractor CUDA)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)

find_package(Boost 1.71.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(chaotic_attractor strangeattractor/main.cu)

target_link_libraries(chaotic_attractor ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

set_target_properties(
        chaotic_attractor
        PROPERTIES
        CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
```

It is not clear to me if NVCC and Boost can get along. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the `CXX` language here is apparently a requirement for Boost.

```makefile
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(chaotic_attractor LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)

...
```

Comment: I edited your answer to use best practices. There is absolutely no need for `enable_language` here. Placing code in between `cmake_minimum_required` and `project` is a _serious_ code smell.